# Meteor: using npm packages for unit testing (instead of atmosphere packages)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor

I want to test my meteor app. Initially I wanted to use some atmosphere package, but it turns out that a lot (almost all of them) are no longer maintained.

Is there a way to use "pure" npm packages (like mocha or jest) in meteor app.

My initial logic for this is to `npm install --save-dev` what I need (e.g. `mocha` & `chai`) and then add a script in `package.json` that would perform the testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed do this. The only atmosphere package you need is dispatch:mocha. This is used by the standard meteor test framework (eg when running `meteor test`).

Mocha itself is an npm package, and whatever others you need such as enzyme, jest etc

Have a read of the Meteor guide on testing https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html

It explains the various kinds of testing available and how to run them.